# Interfaces of ROS classes for mocking and dependency injection

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write unit tests for my class that interacts with various ROS `ServiceClient` and `SimpleActionClient`.  Since I'm fairly confident in ROS and don't want to handle the indeterminacy of network latency in my unit tests, I plan to have my unit tests cover the interface between my class and ROS only.

Hence, I would need to mock the `ServiceClient` and `SimpleActionClient`.  In order to mock, the things I am mocking needs to implement an interface (lest I be forced to use this [uglier method](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.1/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods).

My question is, does the `ServiceClient` and `SimpleActionClient` implement any interface that I can mock?  If not, is there any best practices for mocking common ROS classes?

My current implementation is to use dependency injection to allow me to separate and swap out the concrete ROS stuff with (hopefully) mocked ROS stuff

```
PayloadController::PayloadController(
        ros::ServiceClient& service_client,
        actionlib::SimpleActionClient<...>& action_client)
```

PS:: To my blessing, `tf2_ros::Buffer` implements the `BufferInterface` which allowed me to mock and unit test code that used TF2 easily

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366405/interfaces-of-ros-classes-for-mocking-and-dependency-injection/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resorted to writing my own wrapper to achieve my needs.  Below is an example of wrapping a `SimpleActionClient`

```
#pragma once

#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>
#include "actionlib/client/action_client.h"
#include "actionlib/client/simple_goal_state.h"
#include "actionlib/client/simple_client_goal_state.h"
#include "actionlib/client/terminal_state.h"

template <class ActionSpec>
class SimpleActionClientInterface
{
    protected:
        ACTION_DEFINITION(ActionSpec);
    public:
        virtual void sendGoal(const Goal& goal) = 0;
        virtual void waitForResult() = 0;
        virtual actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState getState() = 0;
};

template <class ActionSpec>
class SimpleActionClientWrapper : public SimpleActionClientInterface<ActionSpec>
{
    protected:
        ACTION_DEFINITION(ActionSpec);

    public:
        SimpleActionClientWrapper(actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>& client) :
            client(client)
        {};

        virtual void sendGoal(const Goal& goal)
        {
            client.sendGoal(goal);
        };

        virtual void waitForResult()
        {
            client.waitForResult();
        };

        virtual actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState getState()
        {
            return client.getState();
        };

    private:
        actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>& client;
};
```

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2021-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0